# TypeScript - Describe function declared inside namespace?

Tags: typescript

If I have a namespace in `global.d.ts` with a function inside:

```
declare namespace MY_NAMESPACE {
  function doSomething(): void
}
```

How can I describe that function then?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "describe"?

Comment: Describe the body of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a `d.ts` file isn't to create a runnable function. It is only used to describe the types of a module that does not have any.

For example: Module **A** is a pure JavaScript package, but you want to use it strongly typed in your TypeScript project. If that is the case, you write a `d.ts` file for that module.

[TypeScript Documentation: Modules .d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)

Comment: I thought it was possible since VSCode wasn`t warning of defining a function. Thanks